# [Vertica][VJDBC](100172) One or more rows were rejected by the server

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop, vertica, impala

I got the following error when loading data from Impala to Vertica with Sqoop.

> Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map
>   task logs     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)  at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused
>   by: java.io.IOException: java.sql.BatchUpdateException:
>   [Vertica]VJDBC One or more rows were rejected by the server.
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:658)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:84)
>     ... 10 more Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException:
>   [Vertica]VJDBC One or more rows were rejected by the server.
>     at com.vertica.jdbc.SStatement.processBatchResults(Unknown Source)
>     at com.vertica.jdbc.SPreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlOutputFormat$AsyncSqlExecThread.run(AsyncSqlOutputFormat.java:231)

And I was running the following command:

> sudo -u impala sqoop export -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=xxx
>   --driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver --connect jdbc:vertica://host:5433/db --username name --password pw --table table --export-dir /some/dir -m 1 --input-fields-terminated-by '\t' --input-lines-terminated-by '\n'
>   --batch

This error was not raised every time. I had several successful tests loading over 2 million rows of data. So I guess there might be some bad data that contains special characters in the rejected rows. This is very annoying because when this error raised, mapreduce job would rollback and retry. In this case, there would be lots of duplicate data in the target table.

Does anyone have idea if there is any sqoop export parameter that can be set to deal with special characters or if there is any way to skip the bad data, which means to disable rollback? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just try something like Talend?

Comment: What is the error for failed map tasks ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may not be just special characters. If you try to stuff `'abc`' into a numeric field, for example, that row would get rejected. Even though you get this error, I believe it not until after the load and all data should be committed that could be committed (but I would verify that).  If you isolate the "missing" rows you might be able to figure out what is wrong with the data or the field definition.

Common things to look for:

1. Stuffing character type data into numeric fields (maybe implicit conversions, or only show up when the values are non-NULL).
2. `NULL` values into `NOT NULL` fields
3. Counting characters and `VARCHAR` octets as equivalent.  `VARCHAR(x)` represents octets, but a UTF-8 character can have multiple octets.
4. Similar to #3, strings too long to fit in designated fields.

In the driver, the batch inserts are being replaced with a `COPY FROM STDIN` statement. You might be able to find the statement in `query_requests` although I'm not sure it will help.

Sqoop doesn't really give you much opportunity to investigate this further (as far as I am aware, I checked the generic JDBC Loader). One could look at the return array for `executeBatch()` and tie this to your execution batch.  Maybe modify the generic JDBC loader?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And you are right. I just double checked with my source data. I believe there are some bad data, like string in a bigint field. However, there is no way to skip the bad data with current version of Sqoop. : (

Comment: You hmight be able to do what I mentioned above, create a new loader based on the JDBC loader and check the executeBatch return array.  I am not sure what kind of batches sqoop does, though.  I would have thought that it would load all the data except the ones that fail based on what I know about how Vertica's `COPY` works. Are you sure this isn't the case?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Problem solved! It turns out the error was raised because some data is longer than definition... copy of vsql can automatically truncate longer data but sqoop can't.

Comment: @yuan0122 Make sure you accept woot's answer if it solved your problem.